# Extending navigation bar to full width

Tags: html, css, width

The navigation bar of my website does not extend to the full height of my webpage. I would like to extend it so it fits the page perfectly. Here is my code.

**Html:**

```
<div id="Nav">
<div id="NavContent">
    <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#Nav {
    width:100%; 
    background-color:#f26522;
}

#NavContent {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:9999px;
}
```

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the natural `padding` and `margin` from the document and the `h1` (which has default values)

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#Nav {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%; 
    background-color:#f26522;
}

#NavContent {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7vLPb/

Fiddle(fullscreen) : http://jsfiddle.net/7vLPb/show/

Comment: there is no need to absolute position in this case. That would not be good practice.

Comment: Its ok when you use it for the entire page to do such adjusting.

Comment: it's completely unnecessary. The issue is normalize wasn't used and the default values of the `body` and `h1` were not reset.

Comment: I myself use it while building websites.Absolute positioning never caused any trouble for me.Also mine containes lesser lines than yours which also gives correct output and thats why i gave you +1 for your answer.

Comment: I know it doesn't cause issues in this case, it's just not good practice. As far as lesser lines you should be reseting the values of the `body` anyways because every browser has their own default. The same goes for `h1`, unless you are going for that 1995 look you're going to be styling that `h1` tag anyways. Most people use an additional stylesheet like normalize.css just for the sole purpose of resetting default values of elements. People can do whatever they want, but I try to do things properly and absolute positioning something should always be a last result.

Answer (score 0):

Go and search 'css reset' and copy the code.

Basically a browser has margin,padding etc. already in place and this can get in the way. So many people use a css reset. Put the css reset at the top of your css document. This should remove the padding and margins that are in your way.

Also make sure you set the width of your navbar to 100%.  Good luck!